# Fingerprinted proxy cache assets

Tags: nginx

Currently I have a proxy cache setup which is very vanilla:

```
proxy_cache_path /path/to/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m;

server {
  # ...
  location / {
    proxy_cache my_cache;
    proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
  }
}
```

Now I got the requirement to handle fingerprinted assets. Unfortunately the fingerprint is in the first part of the URL.

Examples:

```
http://www.example.com/asd9f87asdf/assets/foobar.jpg
http://www.example.com/oihllk8asdf/assets/foobar.jpg
```

Both requests should ask for

```
/assets/foobar.jpg
```

from `proxy_pass` and add the first part of the URL `asd9f87asdf` or `oihllk8asdf` to the used key in the cache.

Is it possible to extract that part of the URL and add it to the proxy cache key?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just redirect any request for `/*/assets` to `/assets`? In this sense, you are still getting the initial request (which does not need to be cached), but then the redirect target would be cached?

Comment: A redirect doesn’t help because the asset can change.

Comment: If the asset can change, they why worry about caching it?

Comment: The asset doesn’t change with the whole initial URL. The fingerprint works but is unfortunately located.